# How do I use Save for Web to output a single image, when using a multi slice document?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, slices

I often have a sliced Photoshop document (because I use it to build my HTML), but sometimes I really need to save a preview of the whole project for the web, to use like a thumbnail for example.
Is there a way to use Save for Web to output a single image when using a multi slice document?
I know I can duplicate no a new document but I would feel more comfortable using only my original document.

Comment: AFAIK there's no option to deactivate slices. But you could clear the slices, then Save for Web, then undo. I wouldn't recommend to do it without duplicate, though. It can be risky if you forget the Undo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *Image > Duplicate* to make a copy of your document
- *View > Clear Slices*
- Save for Web.

Close the duplicate document without saving.